# MongoDB filtering

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, nosql

I have an array, which is a filter for Mongodb.
But it does not work, I can not understand why.

```
Array
(
[deleted] => Array
    (
        [$ne] => 1
    )

    [public] => 1
    [_id] => Array
        (
            [$nin] => Array
                (
                    [0] => MongoId Object
                        (
                            [$id] => 525becec38aa9e28201f1d68
                        )
                    [1] => MongoId Object
                        (
                            [$id] => 525becb438aa9e963a1f1d55
                        )
                    [2] => MongoId Object
                        (
                            [$id] => 525bec7438aa9e8d3a1f1d56
                        )
                    [3] => MongoId Object
                        (
                            [$id] => 525bec1438aa9e6c6d1f1d69
                        )
                    [4] => MongoId Object
                        (
                            [$id] => 525bebcf38aa9e8c3a1f1d57
                        )
                    [5] => MongoId Object
                        (
                            [$id] => 525beb3038aa9e8d3a1f1d55
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I need to find all the objects for which the identifier is not in the list.

Comment: What programming language is that? I think it might be PHP, but I am not sure. Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Please be more specific, and show us what you have tried already.
What MongoDB query have to done?

Comment: I'm trying to get all the objects are not included in the list, the list in the array $nin
if( !empty( $profile['answered'] ) ) $filter['_id']['$nin'][] = $profile['answered'];
                if( !empty( $profile['wrongAnswered'] ) ) $filter['_id']['$nin'] = $profile['wrongAnswered'];
$object = $this->mongo->questions->find( $filter )->limit(1)->sort( array( 'gallery.0' => -1 ) );

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this:

```
$filter = array(
    '_id' => array(
         '$nin' => array(
              new MongoId('525becec38aa9e28201f1d68'),
              //etc...
          )
     ),
     'deleted' => array(
          '$ne' => 1
      )

);

$result = $this->mongo->questions->find($filter)->sort(//however you're sorting);
```

Not sure why you were limiting the results to 1 document, unless that's what you really want.